# css animations webkit issue

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have created a 3d spinning cube using css animations, it works fine in Mozilla, but when i run it in a webkit browser I have the spinning animation, but the 6 images dont translate as they should. If i disable the animation however, the 6 images translate as requested and i have a cube. Has anyone come across this before?

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate{
from {-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
to {-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate{
from {-moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);}
to {-moz-transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateZ(360deg);}
}

.object{
transform-style:preserve-3d;
width:300px;
height:300px;
top: 150px;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
-moz-animation-name:                rotate; 
-moz-animation-duration:            5s; 
-moz-animation-iteration-count:     infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function:     linear;
-webkit-animation-name:             rotate; 
-webkit-animation-duration:         5s; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:  linear;}
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the cube http://jsfiddle.net/timwilks13/SRU34/1/
And the hosted version http://www.bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
.object{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /* ..*/
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/SRU34/2/)